# scope based ref in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have ref for form which is a custom element

```
<form ref="domRef" ...>
```

I have ref for field too, which is another custom element(being used inside the form)

```
<input type="text" ref="domRef" .....>
```

but inside attach() of form's view model I am getting this.domRef is input's reference.

```
attached(){        
     console.log(this.domRef);
}
```

So, as the execution goes on domRef is being overridden by the latest one. Why?

Why domRef's are not different for different scopes?

I cannot use different name for ref as all are being generated dynamically.
Please help me on this if there is any alternative.

> Update
>   After Ashley's Answer:

Custom Element Form has its own VM and Custom Element Field has its own VM too.

**Views:**

```
    <template>
        <form ref="domRef">
                <compose view-model="resources/elements/field" ..... containerLess>
                </compose>
        </form>
    </template>
    <template>
        <input type="text" ref="domRef"></input>
    </template>
```

**View-Models:**

```
    export class Form{
     ..
     attached(){
      console.log(this.domRef); //returns Input's Ref Which is not correct
     }
    }
    export class Field{
     ..
     attached(){
      console.log(this.domRef); //returns Input's Ref Which is correct
     }
    }
```

Then if domRef belongs to the current VM why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging out everything, I got the solution. i.e initializing the domRef at the time of constructing.

```
    export class Form{
     constructor(){
       this.domRef = null;
     }
     attached(){
      console.log(this.domRef); //returns Form's Ref Which is correct
     }
    }
    export class Field{
     constructor(){
       this.domRef = null;
     }
     attached(){
      console.log(this.domRef); //returns Input's Ref Which is correct
     }
    }
```

Strange but Worked.

Answer (score 2):

The `scope` is your VM, not any HTML element, so `this.domRef` is gonna be set to the last element that Aurelia set that property to.

If the name is being generated dynamically, couldn't you just change the name generation code?